Nuxt 3 sidebase change between local login and keycloak
I am using sidebase and keycloak in my nuxt 3 and Vue 3 project and I have been tasked to create an alternative login page to be used in case keycloak is offline.
I thought of first creating said page and use "definedPageMeta" so unauthenticated user could login trough my local apis. However no matter what I do it always redirects to keycloak and I can't find a way to not do that when tinkering with either the auth nor the nuxt configuration files.
This is what I got so far:
login/index.vue
<template>
  My login page
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { definePageMeta } from '#imports';

definePageMeta({
  title: 'Login',
  layout: 'default',
  auth: {
    unauthenticatedOnly: true,
    navigateAuthenticatedTo: '/'
  }
});
</script>

serve/api/auth/[...].ts
import Keycloak from 'next-auth/providers/keycloak';

// @ts-ignore
import { NuxtAuthHandler } from '#auth';

export default NuxtAuthHandler({
  debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  secret: process.env.NUXT_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET,
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt'
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account, profile }: any) {
      if (account && user) {
        return {
          ...token,
          accessToken: account?.access_token,
          idToken: account?.id_token,
          profile: {
            name: profile?.given_name,
            id: profile?.preferred_username
          },
          iss: profile?.iss,
          ...user
        };
      }

      if (account?.expires_at && new Date() > new Date(account?.expires_at)) {
        console.warn('New Token Required');
      }

      return await token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }: any) {
      (session as any).role = token.role;
      (session as any).uid = token.id;
      (session as any).accessToken = token.accessToken;
      (session as any).idToken = token.idToken;
      (session as any).profile = token.profile;
      (session as any).iss = token.iss;

      return await session;
    }
  },
  providers: [
    Keycloak.default({
      clientId: process.env.NUXT_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.NUXT_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET,
      issuer: `${process.env.NUXT_KEYCLOAK_HOST}/realms/${process.env.NUXT_KEYCLOAK_REALM}`,
      httpOptions: {
        timeout: 10000
      }
    })
  ]
});

nuxt.config.ts
modules: [
  ['@pinia/nuxt', {}],
  [
    '@nuxtjs/i18n',
    {
      vueI18n: './i18n.config.ts'
    }
  ],
  [
    '@sidebase/nuxt-auth',
    {
      baseURL: '/myApp/api/auth',
      provider: {
        type: 'authjs',
        defaultProvider: 'keycloak'
      },
      globalAppMiddleware: true
    }
  ]
],
runtimeConfig: {
  public: {
    api: {
      apiBaseUrl: process.env.API_BASE_URL || '',
      isMockActive: process.env.IS_MOCK_ACTIVE === 'true'
    },
    authJs: {
      baseUrl: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL,
      verifyClientOnEveryRequest: true 
    }
  },
  authJs: {
    secret: process.env.NUXT_NEXTAUTH_SECRET
  },
  keycloak: {
    clientId: process.env.NUXT_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.NUXT_KEYCLOAK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    host: process.env.NUXT_KEYCLOAK_HOST,
    realm: process.env.NUXT_KEYCLOAK_REALM
  }
}

